# Flutter VS code plugin stuck Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome

Tags: flutter, dart, vscode-extensions

I am using VS Code for Flutter developement since a long time and up until now, launching the web version from VS code has worked just fine. However, similar to what others have posted I now get a "Waiting for connection from debug service on Chrome...".

The Chrome window opens but the URL just says: "http://localhost:57698/" and the page is white.

If I click reload, the URL changes to "http://localhost:57698/#/" and the page loads correctly. This seem to match other peoples experience for this problem, that hot reloading or similar loads the page.

If I launch the web version from the command line with: "flutter run -d chrome" it also works fine. It is only when launching from VSCode it no longer works (and it has been ok for 2 years). I have tried to restart the whole computer as well as Chrome and VS code and I have done flutter clean, still the same. I have also tested on 2 different computers, no change. Is there some magic thing in Chrome that can get stuck or what could have happened?

My flutter doctor says that all is ok:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on macOS 13.2 22D49 darwin-arm, locale en-ES)
    • Flutter version 2.10.5 at /Users/johanlantz/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5464c5bac7 (10 months ago), 2022-04-18 09:55:37 -0700
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/johanlantz/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.3)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.58.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 109.0.5414.119

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Does someone stucked with it? It works well in others projects in my computer but not with a specific one. Changing the dart plugin version did not solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading the dart and flutter VS code plugins from 3.58.0 to 3.56.0 fixed this (on two separate MacBooks with the same issue).

Comment: I don't know how to control the plugin versions in intellij idea ! any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of the plugin switched to a new API (because an old API is being removed). Unfortunately when running on the web, it *appears* as if the new API is available (the VM Service version number is high enough), but the API is unfortunately not actually available.

A fix is on the way - you can get it early by switching to the Pre-Release version of the extension:

[image: Dart Pre-Release Extension]